# Problems applying a style sheet (XSL) to an (XML) in IE via (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

This works in Firefox, but doesn't work in IE. IE complains about line 18:

```
docCache.stylesheet = xsl;
```

Reporting that:

```
Message: The stylesheet does not contain a document element.  The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document.
```

Here is the function:

```
function display(dname, compt) {    
document.getElementById(dname+"Table").innerHTML="";

// IE
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xml = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.load(dname+".xml");

    xsl = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0");
    xsl.async = false;
    xsl.load(dname+".xsl");

    docCache = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate.3.0");
    docCache.stylesheet = xsl;

    docProcessor = docCache.createProcessor();
    docProcessor.input = xml;

    docProcessor.addParameter("competitor", compt);

    docProcessor.transform();

    document.getElementById(dname+"Table").innerHTML = docProcessor.output;
}
// Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {

        xml=loadXMLDoc(dname+".xml");
        xsl=loadXMLDoc(dname+".xsl");
        xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);    
        xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "competitor", compt);          
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
        document.getElementById(dname+"Table").appendChild(resultDocument);
}
```

}

And the XSL file:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:param name="competitor"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
      The parameter value was: <xsl:value-of select="$competitor"/>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Offhand guess, your stylesheet has some whitespace before the first tag?

Comment: Yes, it does. But clearing that white space did nothing :\

Comment: Check `xsl.parseError.errorCode` and `xsl.parseError.reason` after the `load` call to find out what goes wrong. If the parser finds an error then `errorCode` should be different from 0 and `reason` should tell you the error message.

Comment: It says: System error: -2146697210.

Comment: Just curious, what was wrong, what did `xsl.parseError.reason` tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Are you accessing the files from the filesystem?

If you are loading your files from the file:// protocol, rather than http://, then browser security restrictions may prevent you from reading the files. It does this to prevent people from reading other (private) files from your filesystem.

Try hosting on a webserver and see if your errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests MSXML2 is having trouble reading the XSL (an XML file). If you open the XSL file in IE, does it display fully and correctly without errors?

A possible cause is that the XSL file is using an encoding that IE and MSXML2 do not automatically detect and does not include an XML encoding statement at the top like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
```

Or it could be that the actual encoding of the XSL file and its XML encoding statement do not match.

You could also check that FireFox is able to open and fully display the XSL file. If the file is malformed, FireFox will show you where the error is (while IE often may show you the problem area, or may show you something else entirely).